# How do you add a UILabel to a UICollectionViewCell without custom class?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, storyboard, uicollectionviewcell

I've dragged a UICollectionViewController to the main storyboard and created the corresponding class.

[image]
I've named/connected everything in storyboard and view controller correctly.

[image]
[image]

But I am unable to access objects I've placed in the UICollectionViewCell... for instance I can't set the text property on the  UILabel.

[image]

If I create a custom UICollectionViewCell class and create/connect the @IBOutlet to the UILabel everything works fine.

But do I have to create this custom UICollectionViewCell class?

It looks like the collection view is aware that a label has been added to the cell, based on the tree view in storyboard.

I just want to add a label w/ some default text and want to avoid adding the extra file.

Comment: You need a custom class because your dequeueReusableCell will return a UICollectionViewCell without your label. But to write a custom class for it is really easy.

Comment: I know it's easy and know how to do it.. but seems unnecessary to have to add the custom class for the cell. Storyboard seems to be aware that the cell contains the uilabel object and the code seems to know the identifier for the cell.. seems odd that it also needs a custom class and iboutlet connection created manually

Comment: @seanb123 check my answer

Comment: What you could do is to add the label and the constraints programmatically in the cellForItemAt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do even without creating the custom class, by using the **'Tag'**

For example, give the Tag '101' to your `UICollectionView` label as shown below.

Then in your `cellForRowAt` method:

```
let label = cell.viewWithTag(101) as! UILabel
label.text = "Hi"
```

[image]

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you. This is what I'm looking for. I was hoping to do it w/ just the cell identifier but this does work.

Comment: Happy coding :-) @seanb123

Comment: Hmm.. @lmad how do you get it to show up in the cell?

Comment: @seanb123 Using Tags. Tags are very useful to identify the UI element.

Answer (score 0):

UICollectionView does not have ready made cell templates like UITableView.
You will have to create your own class of UICollectionViewCell.